# Has he come yet or hasn't he come yet?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-meaning

To get the meaning ' Hasn't he come until now ?' what should I ask 'Has he come yet ?or Hasn't he come yet?'

Answer (score 2):

Has he come yet?  -  This is a simple question asking for straightforward information.

*- Has he come yet?
- Yes, he arrived 10 minutes ago.*

Hasn't he come yet? - This can indicate frustration or impatience on the part of the speaker, or at least emphasize an expectation that the person should have come already.

> *Where's Peter?*
>
> *I haven't seen him.*
>
> *Hasn't he come yet?*
>
> *Not yet. I presume he has been delayed.*
>
> *Well, we'll have to start the meeting without him.*

Answer (score 1):

In English, we normally form questions by reversing the natural subject / verb sequence of a statement...

> *John is here* - **statement**
>    *Is John here?* - neutral **question**

But when the question includes *negation*...

> *Isn't John here?* - "loaded" **question**

...this normally implies that the questioner ***expects / expected*** the underlying (positive) statement to be ***true***. Including an adverbial element (such as ***yet, already***) is irrelevant to this general principle.

---

Sometimes the negation might indicate surprise or annoyance - because the speaker already has reason to suspect that John *isn't* present, and seeks confirmation of this.

Other times it might be a "rhetorical" question - speaker suspects (or knows perfectly well) that John *is* present, and the expected answer is ***Yes***...

> *Jack, will you please take out the garbage?*
>    *Isn't John here?* - Jack knows/thinks John is present, and it's usually John's job to take it out